# change UIbutton inside animation block using swift

Tags: ios, animation, swift, uibutton, uikit

Hello i am new to swift and i am trying to create a set of animations and also change an image inside a uibutton. the problem is that its messing up the animation. What am i missing? thanks

As you can see there are some uiTableView and uiViews that i am resizing their heights when a button is being pressed

So i have a button that have an arrow up and when the animation finished i want to change the arrow pointing down with a different image

the animation is messed up when i remove the uibutton setting the animation is working perfectly when i add this line its all get to the start.

is there something wrong with this code?

```
 UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4, delay: 0.1, options: .CurveEaseOut, animations: {

     //changing the heights of scroll view and few tables
     self.WeatherScrollView.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: screenSize.width, height: 44)
     self.WeatherSubView.hidden = true;

     self.NavbarSubView.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:100, width: screenSize.width, height: 44)
     self.apiView.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:145, width: screenSize.width, height: 50)
     self.SearchResultsTable.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:195, width: screenSize.width, height:screenSize.height-196 )
     self.smallHeaderView.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:44, width: screenSize.width, height:60 )

 }, completion: { finished in
     //the problem is here 
     //the button is inside NavbarSubView that is also being animated if its matters
     self.slideBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "arrow_open") ,forState:UIControlState.Normal)            
})
```

Comment: what you want to achieve via animation?

Comment: Please add a better description of what you're trying to achieve and what you're actually getting. How is the animation messed up?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by adding some layout code in viewDidLayoutSubviews

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {

    if ScreenState == true {
        //some repositioning of whatever
        self.screenDevider("open",animate: false);
    }
}
```